# global name 'label' is not defined. What does this error mean?

Tags: python

While adding to the list, I found the following error

I have to use the label word.
However, the following error is displayed.
What should I do?

Python code :

```
asd = 1
def data():
  if 1 == asd:
    f = open('sar2.txt','r')

  a=[]
  for i in f:
    a.append(i.split())

  for c in a:
    c.pop(0)
    c.pop(1)

  a = [[i[0],float(i[1]),float(i[2]),float(i[3]),float(i[4]),float(i[5])] for i in a]
  b = [{type: 'date', label: 'Season Start Date'},'user','nice','system','iowait','idle']
  a.insert(0,b)
  f.close()
  return a

data()
```

sar2.txt :

```
2017/06/29 00:01:01 all 0.24 0.00 0.16 0.27 99.33
2017/06/29 00:02:01 all 0.13 0.00 0.04 0.13 99.70
2017/06/29 00:03:01 all 1.05 0.00 0.38 0.26 98.30
2017/06/29 00:04:01 all 0.44 0.00 0.10 0.15 99.32
2017/06/29 00:05:01 all 0.25 0.00 0.08 0.22 99.45
```

Error :

```
    b = [{type: 'date', label: 'Season Start Date'},'user','nice','system','iowait','idle']
NameError: global name 'label' is not defined
```

How can I fix the error?

Comment: Maybe what you want is 'label'.

Comment: Should use "label" instead of label, otherwise it is parsed as the name of another variable instead of string.

Comment: The error means there is no (local or global) **variable** named `label` defined, yet a reference to it is being made to it on the line shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want to use strings not variables as keys in your dict, so your code should look like this

```
b = [{'type': 'date', 'label': 'Season Start Date'},'user','nice','system','iowait','idle']
```

You also defined `type` as a key for your dict, it won't give you an error because these is a [built-in type() function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) but you should never use it like a key for your dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Reducing to the minimal error:

```
>>> {asdf: 3}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'asdf' is not defined
>>> {'asdf': 3}
{'asdf': 3}
```

When creating the dictionary, you probably intended to have strings for keys.